How to combine row with the same ID values into a single line or row without using String_AGG()
Sample - before
ID  A       B       C       D                                                        
---------------------------------
100 NULL    Bravo   NULL    Delta                                               
100 Alpha   Null    Charlie Delta                                       
101 Echo    Null    Golf    Null                                        
102 Null    Fox     Golf    Null                                            

After
ID  A       B       C       D                                                        
----------------------------------
100 Alpha   Bravo   Charlie Delta                                      
101 Echo    Null    Golf    Null                                          
102 Null    Fox     Golf    Null                                                

We already solve this but The query takes time to fetch when using STRING_AGG() or other functions.

What should this mean "the query takes time"? What exactly is slow, why do you think STRING_AGG is an issue?

For the data you happened to show, aggregating by ID and then selecting the max of the four columns will work:
SELECT ID, MAX(A) AS A, MAX(B) AS B, MAX(C) AS C, MAX(D) AS D
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID;

